# Force update of a Delayed Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

We've been using the BindingBase.Delay property to allow for better user experience. A value of 500 worked very well in our application but it's causing some problems. It's very possible for a user to click the Save button before the update has been committed to the VM causing the property to not be updated.

Is there some command to force all delayed values to be pushed back the VM immediately?

Comment: Why delay a binding you don't want delayed?

Comment: We want the binding delayed when the user is busy typing in a textbox to avoid firing propertychanged causing validation on each keystroke. We also don't want validation to only happen when the user moves way from the control. What we're hoping for an elegant way to tell WPF that "Hey, we're all good with you pushing the values back to VMs right now".

Comment: I don't think any "elegant" way exists.  You can probably hack that crap in the codebehind, but it'll not be elegant...